sich aus etwas verabschieden
I have read/heard the following sentence in the "Schlafende Hunde" TV series:

Er hat sich aus unserem Leben verabschiedet.

Context: a woman is talking about her ex-husband, a cop that left home months ago.
Does "verabschieden" mean "say goodbye" here? If so, is there a difference between "von etwas verabschieden" (say goodbye to something) and "aus etwas verabschieden" ? I only see examples with "von" in DWDS.

Perhaps there's a better translation than "say goodbye" here. You can say goodbye to something, not from or out of something. But even DWDS gives "jmdm. auf Wiedersehen sagen" as the first meaning. Anyway, the DWDS usage database had other examples to ponder: " Ich wollte dich selbst aus diesem Haus verabschieden!" "Da du ja sowieso da hochkletterst... Hör zu... ...ich muss mich wirklich dringend aus diesem Aufzug verabschieden."

It's figurative as in to sail away.

Both DWDS and wiktionary seem to be missing the use "sich aus etwas verabschieden" that is not comprised in any of the meanings they list.
"Sich aus etwas verabschieden" is mostly used in a figurative sense, which means that it's not about saying goodbye as much as about leaving something or giving up on something, where "etwas" is most often a circle of people or a group (of people,  organisations, countries ...), but it can also be a contract or something similar that defines a group.

Er hat sich aus unserem Verein verabschiedet.

means he doesn't attend our meetings any more and isn't an (active) member of the club any more.

Er verabschiedete sich von unserem Verein.

can also just mean that he says goodbye, e.g. for the day or for an  absence.
More examples:

Die USA werden sich nächstes Jahr aus dem Pariser Klimaabkommen verabschieden. (This means they will leave the climate accord.)
Großbritannien hat sich aus der EU verabschiedet.
Du hast dich aus unserer Freundschaft doch längst verabschiedet!

Note that verabschieden is quite often used in this figurative sense, even with von:

Die Regierung hat sich von ihren Sparvorsätzen für dieses Jahr schon im Mai verabschiedet.

